# Call airdrop contract method keep report error "Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas"

Tags: ethereum, web3js, airdrop

I had deployed a ERC20 token on ropsten testnet [MyToken](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xcf3afc7e21da35559269f7503b843ac543392ae0)
. Now I want to send my token to multiple addresses. After google and some research I found [OMG Airdropper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29098/sending-tokens-to-multiple-addresses/29182) may work. So i deployed [airdrop on ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xCF3aFC7e21Da35559269F7503b843ac543392aE0#code) with the same key as MyToken contract.

I use web3js invoke 'multisend' method on airdrop contract, but got error:

```
(node:70819) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:
```

Checked transaction receipt "gasUsed" is not exceed gasLimit:

```
{
 "blockHash": 
 "0xb14df1fda48c44adb75249b46921b0a2889325ccd5335fc4282206a6731d03ed",
 "blockNumber": 3423377,
 "contractAddress": null,
 "cumulativeGasUsed": 1440969,
 "from": "0x7b4d9ef0740f75dbc79222a323246a3659609896",
 "gasUsed": 30479,
 "logs": [],
 "logsBloom": "0x...many 0",
 "status": false,
 "to": "0xcf3afc7e21da35559269f7503b843ac543392ae0",
 "transactionHash": 
 "0x53c7b6842308dec6be5ced3fd1cbb53848c73161da1eb0cfb323c3eb847eebd7",
 "transactionIndex": 15
 }
```

test code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var Web3 = require('web3');
var abi = require('./abi.json');
var _ = require('lodash');
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');


var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/secure_key"));
var inputFile = 'smalldata.csv';

const main = async (addrs, tokens) => {
    console.log(`web3 version: ${web3.version}`)

var contractJson = abi.abi;
var tokenAddress = "0x57fdf8001d1c240d4cbfc82b2fede932960dc310";
var myAddress = "0x7b4d9ef0740f75dbc79222a323246a3659609896";
var privateKey = "81d4f6e4b9d628fa15a9ff98f610e87d2662348c5666a7bf0fc39edf74f27b38";
var abiArray = abi.abi;
var contractAddress = "0xCF3aFC7e21Da35559269F7503b843ac543392aE0";

var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);
console.log(`num transactions so far: ${count}`);

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, {
    from: myAddress
});

var rawTransaction = {
    "from": myAddress,
    "nonce": "0x" + count.toString(16),
    "gasPrice": "0x003B9ACA00",
    "gasLimit": "0x200B20",
    "to": contractAddress,
    "value": "0x0",
    "data": contract.methods.multisend(tokenAddress, addrs, tokens).encodeABI(),
    "chainId": "0x03",
    "gas": "0x30D40"
};

var privKey = new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex');
var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
tx.sign(privKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

console.log(`Attempting to send signed tx:  ${serializedTx.toString('hex')}`);
var receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
console.log(`Receipt info:  ${JSON.stringify(receipt, null, '\t')}`);
}

var parser = parse({
delimiter: ','
}, function (err, data) {
let addressList = [];
let tokensList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    addressList.push(data[i][0]);
    tokensList.push(data[i][1]);
}

let addrsList = _.chunk(addressList, 2);
let tokenList = _.chunk(tokensList, 2);

main(addrsList[0], tokenList[0]);
});

fs.createReadStream(inputFile).pipe(parser);
```

sorry for not proper format code. Format well code at [code on gist](https://gist.github.com/jerry-sl/18089aacea9bf24ba8db2b75c7273508)

csv data is:

```
0x7710f02222Ae6B4b2C308d98526B1D719D6ff2D5,188
0x34dB0eaDFfFE6ed5C4458badCA042F79ECF2a2A7,128
0xb3d475eB29E4fa88D5dB40d29D1AEa6A3C5cB3C9,288
0x5875A89a2043F0eAA858a26610fF58B4f5514e52,188
```

**Any** suggestion or help will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you run `web3.eth.estimateGas({from: myAddress, to: contractAddress, data: contract.methods.multisend(tokenAddress, addrs, tokens).encodeABI()}, (e, r) => console.log(r));`? Is `addrs.length == 4` (based on the csv data you posted)? Also, does your airdrop contract address own enough tokens to cover the transfers (at least 792 based on your sample data)?

Comment: contract owner has enough balance.
estimateGas cause "Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction"

Comment: The problem is token ownership. You need to transfer tokens to the airdrop contract first. Etherscan shows the airdrop contract isn’t holding any tokens.